# $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is this statement true? It's easy to prove the forward direction:
$$Av=\lambda v\Rightarrow\lambda (Av)=\lambda(\lambda v)\Rightarrow A(\lambda v)=\lambda^2 v\Rightarrow A(Av)=\lambda^2 v\Rightarrow A^2v=\lambda^2 v$$
But the backward direction is eluding me. I figured the contrapositive statement, $Av\neq\lambda v\Rightarrow A^2v\neq\lambda^2 v$, might help, but I don't see how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if $A=-I$ ?

Comment: The reverse direction needs some interpretation. For example, $(-1)^2$ is an eigenvalue of $I^2$ but $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $I$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The backward direction is false. Consider that $A^2v=\lambda^2 v$. Then $(A^2-\lambda^2I)v=0$, so $(A-\lambda I)(A+\lambda I)v=0$, implying that at least one of $\lambda$ or $-\lambda$ are eigenvalues of $A$, but not necessarily $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** @ErickWong 's comment shows this answer isn't one. I'll leave it here rather than deleting it since others may be tempted by the same thinko.

In the real plane rotation through a quarter of a circle has no (real) eigenvalues but its square is $-I$, which has eigenvalue $-1$ with multiplicity $2$.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the question.  The phrasing suggests that you intend it to be a counterexample, but it doesn't appear to contradict anything, since there is no $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ for which $\lambda^2 = -1$.

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks. See my edit.